# Istio kiali dashboard shows as unknown traffic inbound from ingress gateway

Tags: istio, minikube, istio-kiali

I have deployed an application in my minikube cluster, the application access is ok via ingress gateway service at http://172.18.97.73:31566/.

```
minikube ip
  172.18.97.73

kubectl get svc -n istio-system
  istio-ingressgateway   NodePort    10.99.4.153     <none>        15021:31123/TCP,80:31566/TCP,443:32094/TCP,15012:30004/TCP,15443:30369/TCP   3h48m
```

but kiali graph shows as unknown the origin of the traffic.

[kiali graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgtic.png)

i can't understand what is wrong, could you help me?

the manifest is here:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: application
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8082
  selector:
    app: app
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: http-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: application-vs
spec:
  hosts:
  - "*"
  gateways:
  - "default/http-gateway"
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: application.default.svc.cluster.local
        port:
          number: 8082
```

Comment: More often than not, these `unknowns` are either Prometheus metrics scraping, or kubernetes API healthchecks (readiness/liveness probes)

Comment: Does istio is enabled for istio-ingressgateway depolyment in istio-system namespace? If not please enable and check.